# CreateSalesforceObject creating multiple records

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, salesforce1-app, marketing-cloud-connect

I have an unsubscribe cloud page, whose link is attached to an email. When users click on that link, it should create a record in a Salesforce org and load the unsubscribe page. But sometimes it is creating multiple records and sometimes two records.

```
%%[
var @patientID, @getAccId, @row1, @accountId, @optStatusId
set @patientID = RequestParameter('pid')

set @getAccId = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Account", "Id", "APS_Patient_ID__c", "=", @patientID)

IF rowcount (@getAccId) > 0 then
SET @row1 = row(@getAccId,1)
SET @accountId  = field(@row1, "Id")
ENDIF

IF @accountId !='' THEN
@optStatusId = CreateSalesforceObject('APS_Opt_Status__c', 2,
'APS_Patient__c', @accountId,
'APS_Program_Opt_Status__c', 'Opt Out')
ENDIF
]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using ">" operator instead of "==" for ROWCOUNT function. If you change it to

```
IF rowcount (@getAccId) == 1 then
```

..it will limitate to a single record.